# php regular expression find and replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$string = '20110306';
$pattern = '(\d{6})(\d{2})';
$replacement = '$101';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

I want it to echo `20110301`

I used http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to come up with the search and replacement pattern, maybe I am missing something when it comes to replacing the found pattern.

It gives me the following warning:

**Message: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '('**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two changes:

1. You need to place the regex between a pair delimiters, say `/` as::

   ```
   $pattern = '/(\d{6})(\d{2})/';
   ```
2. `$101` refers to group number `101`. You meant to append `01` to group number `1` so change

   ```
   $replacement = '$101';
   ```

   to

   ```
   $replacement = '${1}01';
   ```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/G7uLJ)

Answer (score 0):

replace the () by ~~ in $pattern.

Comment: or indeed, any other valid regex delimiter character.